Intersection of Number Theory and other areas of mathematics
My favorite thing in mathematics is discovering the intersection of number theory and other areas of math. I think of Algebraic Number Theory, Arithmetic Geometry, Analytic Number Theory as the main areas where there questions, theorems, and proofs involve algebra, analysis (largely complex analysis), and algebraic geometry (which admittedly touches a lot of math), but I have been delighted to learn about other areas like Arithmetic Dynamics (in polynomial dynamics), Hilbert's 10th problem (in logic) and the Arithmetic of Hyperbolic manifolds (in Topology/geometry).What other neat intersections of Number Theory and the rest of math are there? Do number theory and real analysis meet somewhere? Differential equations?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langlands_program

The following is from what I remember of a seminar by Steve Lester.  You might find more by looking at his papers on arXiv.
Consider the differential operator $\nabla^2$ acting on the space $V$ of smooth functions on the unit square $[0,\pi]^2$, which vanish on the boundary of the square.
If we want to find eigenfunctions of this operator with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then we can take functions of the form $$ \sin(nx)\sin(my),\qquad n^2+m^2=-\lambda,$$
where the boundary conditions force $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$.
If I remember correctly these form a basis for each eigenspace. Thus the number of ways of writing an integer $d$ as the sum of two squares, is given by the dimension of the eigenspace of $\nabla^2$ (acting on $V$), corresponding to eigenvalue $-d$.
Presumably this is the start of a deeper connection between number theory and differential operators (or I missed the point of the seminar).
In the other direction, number theory has numerous applications in other areas.  For example in this paper, it is shown that two spaces are homotopically distinct (cannot be morphed into each other), by showing that such a deformation would imply the existence of an impossible unit in a cyclotomic number field.
